# Is this a normal Disk Partition Configuration?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I'm new to mac I just got my first macbook used last week. I was trying to install Windows 10 via boot camp and it told me it could not due to some issue and to check Disk Utility. I have used Linux and Windows to a lesser degree most of my life, but I am embarrassed to say I don't fully understand this. I ran `diskutil list` & `diskutil apfs list` and this is the output. I saw these commands on some other post and thought they may be helpful. This is probably completely normal. I am sure I just want to understand. I am on the newest update of Catalina MBP Mid 2017. Also, it is not super important to get Boot Camp running Windows. I was just experimenting, but does anyone see an obvious reason why there would be an issue? Thank you!

[image: DISK UTILITY]

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled - Data         127.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume RJ                      11.2 GB    disk1s5

SuperSecretCPU:~ adminMan$ diskutil apfs list
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 A7F6C36A-FBDB-4322-831A-9FC2CEF2606A
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      250685575168 B (250.7 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   140339167232 B (140.3 GB) (56.0% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       110346407936 B (110.3 GB) (44.0% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 958D8FFE-D633-4F06-A962-CBDD37A8E6F5
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       250685575168 B (250.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 A7C6B5CE-2F45-3C34-B29C-317C531A82E8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Untitled - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         127352475648 B (127.4 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 1A886DD1-7F92-4787-B32A-02620DF632E8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         83750912 B (83.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 5806096A-0C66-4F74-9773-20B8D47F2E2A
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         528502784 B (528.5 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 5E468A33-0424-49C6-9249-42F0CDF2CFDE
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1074810880 B (1.1 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 612780D1-B6D1-47E4-9678-E5AE176EB13A
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (System)
        Name:                      RJ (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /
        Capacity Consumed:         11161202688 B (11.2 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Comment: *...it told me it could not due to some issue and to check Disk Utility.*  I doubt that the error message was that vague.  To help you as to what the problem is, we'd need some more details.  As to whether or not your partition is "normal;"  what's "normal?"  You appear to have the *default* layout.

Comment:  Sadly I'm at work and can't commit to the bootcamp installation process replicate the error and  copy paste its output at the moment. I was recalling from memory that was just the gist of the error message. As for if its normal question Im used to a linux layout typically 3 partitions or Windows having one 1 though I understand windows 10 has changed that.  I literally have never used mac ever until last week so given the error message combined with my understanding of other OS's and lack of knowledge of mac os I thought I would ask, not intentionally trying to be vague. Thanks anyway

Comment: No biggie.  Just when you get back, be sure to get the error message so we can direct you.  Personally, I’m not a fan of BC - I prefer to virtualize so I can move the appliance from machine to machine (i.e disaster recovery).  The layout you have is the default layout, so you’re good.  You’ll discover that macOS is much more powerful than Linux.

Comment: If you can not get the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10, then you may want to try installing using a flash drive. The Boot Camp Assistant can be picky and there is no requirement by Microsoft that you use this application.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply - Yes.

What you're seeing is the new [Apple File System (APFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) which isolates a disk into *containered* volumes. Volumes in an APFS container is analogous to partitions in a drive.

In Disk Utility, you can see you have your `Untitled - Data` Volume for your everyday reads/writes, and a `RJ` volume intended to be apart of apple's security which is designed to be unwritable even to you if you tried without disabling SIP and remounting the root filesystem so foreign programs don't alter and corrupt the macOS system files (malware, you, etc)

The reason the partitioning in `diskutil list` and `diskutil list apfs` may seem strange is APFS is designed to expand and shrink. Meaning all volumes can utilize the entire disk until full which is why you see overlaping disk sizes of your entire disk size.

Comment: I think you've got the descriptions of the volumes the wrong way round. ‘RJ’ is the system volume, shown as mounted at `/`, therefore is read-only. ‘Untitled - Data’ is mounted at `/System/Volumes/Data` and is therefore the one that is writable, also Disk Utility shows the home folder in the screenshot indicating the user's home directory is on this volume.